# Android: disabling highlight on listView click

Tags: android, android-listview, highlighting

I want to disable the orange highlight that occurs when touching a listView row. So far in my xml I have tried the following:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

More information: I want there to be zero difference when a user touches the screen on this listView object.

Answer (score 687, accepted):

Add this to your xml:

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

And for the problem this may work (I'm not sure and I don't know if there are better solutions):

You could apply a [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource) to your TextView.

Comment: if transparent still darkens the selection a little, perhaps it's not defined as completely transparent. Try #00000000 instead, this is totally invisible.

Comment: Perfect solution for me. I've tried setting a transparent selector XML drawable for the background of the listviews surrounding layout but this lead to the aforementioned orange bar on ICS devices.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I use a `Fragment` for the list. The XML layout contains a `LinearLayout` and multiple `TextView` items. Where should I disable the row highlight, please?

Comment: From Java Code, you can do `listView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);`

Comment: @RoflcoptrException -> "You could apply a ColorStateList to your TextView" - this is a good option, if the list rows are not clickable. As soon as the textview is clickable, the onClick event of the list itself will not fire.

Comment: Other code alternative would be `listView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0));`

Comment: Strangely, setting android:listSelector to `@null` did not work.  I had to explicitly set to `@android:color/transparent` to get rid of the yellow selected state drawable.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It actually answers the question with code rather than giving references to fix it.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work without `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"` from Mushtaq answer

Comment: I tried everything in a PreferenceActivity, but none of those worked. Can somebody help me? It is fustrating to get always that orange selector.

Comment: i am geeting frustrated because this line of code was working fine since last year now i edit some code than it stop working, i did contro +z also, but now  this code is is not working

Comment: above solution worked 50% but ImageView gets highlighted. For example, If listview has each view with ImageView's as edit button and delete button. Clicking on a specific view, ImageView gets highlighted.

Answer (score 190):

RoflcoptrException's answer should do the trick,but for some reason it did not work for me, So I am posting the solution which worked for me, hope it helps someone

```
<ListView 
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

Answer (score 101):

The orange highlight effect is a [style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) on the ListView.  [This article](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/) gives a good overview of how to override the listView style.

Essentially, you have a selector that specifies different style elements based on the current state.

see this for short and quick solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242564/185022

Comment: Will this method allow me to have a different style for each listView object? Also, is it possible to avoid the issue I brought up in Sebi's answer?

Comment: Yes, you can override any style attributes.  You can specifically assign a style to each ListView using the style="@style/MyStyle" attribute as described in the first link.

Comment: I am sorry but this shouldn't be the answer. Changing the `listSelector` should be it.

Answer (score 64):

From [ListView: Disable Focus Highlight](https://groups.google.com/g/android-developers/c/A8kq97UZ0pA?pli=1):

When you set your `ListAdapter` use the following code:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MyList, Layout, c, 
                new String[] { "Name", "Score" }, to) 
{ 
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
};
```

This will override the `BaseAdapter` class.  It also cancels the white border between cells.

Comment: Invalid, that's disabled the selection behaviour (OnItemClicked won't fire) for the item

Comment: This is a good solution because whether a listview item is highlighted is more of a behavioral issue than an aesthetic one. So, you can use this for the listviews that you don't want to have the property of being selectable. A global style doesn't really make sense, since you know you're eventually going to want a listview that *can* be selected, and using styles for behavior to me seems wrong. They should not have semantic meaning, only aesthetic. The property of selectability is a semantic thing.

Comment: Apart from that this is not the answer to this question, overriding `isEnabled` to disable an item is not the way to disable it! Documentation says that `isEnabled` is supposed to determine if an item is a separator.

Answer (score 40):

add this also to ur XMl along with listselector..hope it will work

```
<ListView
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I want to solve the problem that the whole listView is hightlighted (white color in my case) when scrolling (Only happen before Android 2.3). And It works.

Comment: "#00000000" and "@android:color/transparent"  for kind of variety?

Comment: @Androider ya in 2011 I was letting people know it works both ways... Definitely today you wont need #000000

Answer (score 31):

If you are using `ArrayAdapter` or `BaseAdapter` to populate the list items. `Override` the `isEnabled` method and return `false`.

```
 @Override
  public boolean isEnabled (int position) {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

After a few 'google'ing and testing on virtual and real devices, I notice my below code works:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, strText) {
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    { 
            return false; 
    } 
};
```

notice that I've omitted the `areAllItemsEnabled()` portion.

Comment: this worked for me . however , doesn't it mean that if there is a drawable for the rows that has the disabled state , it will also change their image ? is it possible to disable clicking and yet not change the drawable ?

Comment: This has a side effect causing ListView not to show dividers.

Answer (score 11):

Nothing helps me but this:

`transparent_drawable.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

`layout.xml`:

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/transparent_drawable"
```

Answer (score 7):

in code

```
listView.setSelector(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.transparent));
```

and add small transparent image to drawable folder.

Like: 
transparent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 6):

For me `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` is the way to go. `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`  is of no use. Note that I am using a custom listview with a number of objects in each row.

Comment: Yeah, `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` allows the view respond to touch, and thus (as far as I can test) its background takes effect rather than the listView's listSelector. If its background is the default transparent then nothing is drawn. When we make a view clickable it also becomes `focusableInTouchMode`, and that's why clickable views get their background drawn from a possible selector like `android:background="@drawable/list_selector_highlight"`

Answer (score 5):

You only need to add:
`android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative:

```
listView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```

or

```
listView.setSelector(new StateListDrawable());
```

Answer (score 1):

There is fast and easy way to do this:
In method:

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //TODO
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
}
```

Hope it'll help ;)

Comment: This c# not java

Comment: I think most android programmers are still using java because that is what Android Studio supports, but C# can of cause be used. I just want to clarify that this is C# :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the highlight for a single list view item, but keep the cell enabled, set the background color for that cell to disable the highlighting.

For instance, in your cell layout, set `android:background="@color/white"`

Answer (score 0):

you can just get the `pos` that you get from the `onItemClick`
and do:

```
listView.setItemChecked(pos, false);
```

that's the best way i know of