# Non clickable ListView

Tags: android, listview

Android does a ListView always have to be clickable? E.g.. you just want to display a end list of something that doesn’t go further?

Cheers,

Mike.

Comment: Just that when I display something in a listview and put my finger on the screen, it highlights like it will take you to a new activity if I push it harder. I just want the list to scroll! Is that my layout xml that is making it do that???

Comment: You should be able to find what you're looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/android-disabling-highlight-on-listview-click. Looks like there are some options that you can try with the theme for the ListView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: disabling highlight on listView click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/android-disabling-highlight-on-listview-click)

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the methods,

> ListView::addFooterView(View view)

This shall appear at the end of the list.

Comment: I want the opposite of that, I don’t want the list to go anywhere, just a final list. The scenario is a user selects a beach from a list, it then goes to a beach detail page, they can then click on to view all the facilities for that beach in a list. That’s it, the only way forward is back.

Comment: Make the last item in the list a "back" listitem that returns the user to wherever you want to return them. If you don't really want the list to lead anywhere then don't use ListView, table the items

Comment: Dear Mike, what you want is when you traversing back to the list, you want to show the item which user had clicked? (eg., list contains 100 items, user clicked on 90th item and shows some screen and when presses back the list again should show 90th item?)