# Read json file and display information on a textview list

Tags: android, json, android-listview, textview

Is it possible to have a viewlist without the rows being clickable? I have information I want read in from a json file (I can do that) and then display that information in a list (I don't know how to do that atm (I do need help with that as well, but I'll try a bit more myself first)), but if I press on a row I don't want that to be highlighted for a few seconds. I tried changing ListView to TextView, but then the setAdapter gives an error. Is it possible to  do that?

Comment: It's definitely possible to change the behavior of ListView so that you don't notice or react to clicks. There is some info on keeping the ListView and making it non-selectable here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/android-disabling-highlight-on-listview-click

Comment: you can use `android:listSelector=@android:color/transparent`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is use `setItemsCanFocus` on your list view. This allows you to set whether the list itmes are focusable (i.e. can be highlighted). You can find more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setItemsCanFocus%28boolean%29) in the android docs for ListView.