# Android - Disable ListView Selection Highlight but Keep OnClick enabled

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to disable the highlight that appears when the user selects a row (listSelector) from code. I don't want to disable the onClick and enabled settings (I still want to listen to clicks, just want to remove the highlight).

Comment: Which adapter are you using?

Comment: A simple ArrayAdapter<String>. Will it matter?

Comment: "I want to disable the highlight that appears when the user selects a row" -- why? What about the users that use arrow keys, D-pad, and the like for navigating your app? Please allow your app to be used by *all* users, not just those who use the touchscreen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4075045/1005846. Hope it will help

Comment: @CommonsWare well, I don't want to support hard keyboard and I won't :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a drawable that has a transparent color in it, something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_disabled_holo_light" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused_holo" />

</selector>
```

And then set by code or by XML:

```
listView.setSelector(R.drawable.my_transparent_selector);
```

The javadoc for this method says:

> Set a Drawable that should be used to highlight the currently selected item.

and the XML attribute is:

> android:listSelector

You can play with all the states, remember that you also have the focus state.

Comment: From code, Nicolas, not the XML. I can handle it already from XML using listSelector attribute.

Comment: I do not know why you need in that way, so keep two files and play with them.

Comment: No, after edit, it's working fine. I am using a some sort of checkbox instead of row highlight. Your answer works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Specify `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` in your `ListView` XML.

Comment: Very easy and does the trick!

Answer (score 4):

I have done this way:

By adding two properties of **ListView**.

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

**Your ListView** should looks like below:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent">

</ListView>
```

**Done**

Answer (score 1):

try `listview.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Comment: This one was easiest for me, who goes for a programmatic approach thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The highlight effect is a style on the listSelector. You can override the listSelector style.

This is a example with a listview : [Android: disabling highlight on listView click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/android-disabling-highlight-on-listview-click)