# How set ListView not clickable

Tags: android, android-listview, clickable, android-selector

I have this `ListView` that just needs to show data.
So I don't want to make it clickable. 
First I've tried changing XML listview to:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="false" >
```

But it didn't work.
So to solve my problem I set through code:

```
  list.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```

but I can't believe there's no better solution. Any idea?

Comment: One way: `ListView.setOnClickListener(null);` OR add `android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` OR add in the layout `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: I think the clickable attribute only set this property for the view. If you want to set the items not clickable you should their clickable attribute to false. Hope this helps

Comment: @g00dy just reply with your comment so I can set as Accepted Answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: disabling highlight on listView click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/android-disabling-highlight-on-listview-click)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Here it is, following the comment:

One way to do so is:
`ListView.setOnClickListener(null);` OR

You can add `android:focusable="false"` `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` OR

another way in the layout `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`

Cheers.

Comment: list.setOnClickListener(null) gave me an error everytime, but list.setOnItemClickListener(null); worked perfectly.

Answer (score 55):

Just  override [isEnabled(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) in your adapter and return false

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This method prevented the separator lines from showing in between my list items. Instead, I set the following property in the XML of the ListView `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` and it worked for me.

Comment: how to do it with `BaseAdapter` @Arun

Comment: Maybe you should override [areAllItemsEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html#areAllItemsEnabled()) and return `false` too. Otherwise, the `isEnabled` method may not have effect.

Answer (score 12):

override the below method. Return false to say all the items are not clickable.

```
 @override
  public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
  }
```

And override below method to return which item is not clickable

```
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if(position == your_item_pos) {
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this method?

Comment: in your adapter class

Comment: its @Override
 public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
  return false;
 }

Comment: This method prevented the separator lines from showing in between my list items. Instead, I set the following property in the XML of the ListView `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

it changes the on-clicked color to same as when it is not clicked!
so it appears as if it is plain text...it's a work around.

Comment: or
listView1.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);

Answer (score 2):

Just copy this method in your adapter class.
Nothing to do .........

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {

    return false;
}
```

You may set any condition to make some selected item unclickable.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    //Y for non clickable item
      if(data_list.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:focusable="true"
```

to any of the item inside listview now listview wont clickable

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set android:enabled="false" to the listview and it would do the trick..why to unneccesary keep overriding methods..

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: This also disables the scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

```
listView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

In  **Adapter.getView()**

```
i.setOnClickListener( null );
i.setLongClickable( false );
i.setClickable( false );
```

Comment: I'd like to set everything by XML, I can't believe I need to manage it by code

Comment: @AntonioCalì the common android beginner's pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

In fact,
@override isEnabled() and 
setOnClickListener(null) 
setClickable(false)
setLongClickable(false)
There are not working for me.
I solve it by override performItemClick

```
@Override
public boolean performItemClick(View view, int position, long id) {
 if(!clickAble){
     return false;
 }
    return super.performItemClick(view,position,id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your ListView item may have a focusable or clickable element, please try the following approach either in XML Layout file or in code:

1. Add this attribute to the root ViewGroup element of your ListItem XML file (i.e. LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ...) :

   > android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
2. Add this line to your List Adapter method which is responsible for creating/recycling the list item (most probably `getView()` or `newView()`), while parent is the ViewGroup of list item:

   `parent.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);`

Answer (score 0):

Only using `list.requestFocusFromTouch()` in the `onResume()` method of the containing fragment worked for me.

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score -1):

> *I have this ListView that just needs to show data. So I don't want to make it clickable.*

I have done this in one of my projects, and the sample bellow works fine.

Basically, you just need:

- a data source (ArrayList, for example)
- a ListView Widget
- an ArrayAdapter, in order to bind the data source with the ListView

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.sample.listview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         // data source
         String[] arrayData = {"Debian", "Ubuntu", "Kali", "Mint"};

         // ListView Widget from a Layout
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

         // an ArrayAdapter (using a layout as model for displaying the array items)
         ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main_list_item_layout, arrayData);

         // binding the ArrayAdapter with the ListView Widget
         listView.setAdapter(aa);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**
--->*Make sure that the ListView Widget is using wrap_content for layout_width and layout_height*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sample.listview.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mainListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  <---- HERE
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" <---- HERE
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**main_list_item_layout.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainListItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    >

</TextView>
```

**That's it:** a ListView not clickable, just presenting data on the screen.