# Make ListView NOT clickable in order to be able to click views on its parent

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I've placed a `ListView` on top of another view and I want the list to just display some changing data and the user shouldn't have any interaction with the list.
The parent view of the list has some buttons on it which I need to be able to reach through the list.
I tried many of the proposed solutions here but none of them work for me.

You can see the comments for the various solutions (solution combinations) I tried.

Any suggestions???

extended `ListView`:

```
public class ItemList extends ListView {

    private MyListAdapater myListAdapater;
    private Item[] items;

    public ItemList(Context context, int rows) {
        super(context);
        items = new Item[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i] = new item(context, "Bla Bla Bla");
        }


        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
        layoutParams.setMargins(pxToDp(8), 0, 0, pxToDp(12));
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        myListAdapater = new MyListAdapater(context, items);
        setAdapter(myListAdapater);
        setDivider(null);
        int rowMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        setDividerHeight(pxToDp(8));
        setSelector(R.color.Transparent);
//        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//                return false;
//            }
//        });
//        setFocusable(false);
//        setClickable(false);
//        setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
//        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        setSelection(myListAdapater.getCount() - 1);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }

    protected int pxToDp(int px) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, px, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

//    @Override
//    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//        return true;
//    }

   }
```

List Adapter:

```
public class MyListAdapater extends BaseAdapter {

    private Item[] listData;
    private Context context;

    public MyListAdapater(Context context, Item[] listData) {
        this.Item = listData;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    //    @Override
    //    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    //        return false;
    //    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();


            convertView = listData[position];
            holder.item = (Item) convertView;
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            //convertView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            //    @Override
            //    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //        return true;
            //    }
            //});

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }



    static class ViewHolder {
        Item item;
    }
}
```

- The Items in the list are views themselves

Thank you

**EDIT:**

I tried adding the list in xml and still can't click the view behind the list.

I tried a test project with the following layout:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.listtest.MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/Blue">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClickTestButton"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/test_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:listSelector="@color/Transparent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

and in the activity:

```
myListAdapter = new MyListAdapater(this, items);
testList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.test_list);
testList.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
testList.setOnItemClickListener(null);
testList.setEnabled(false);
```

now this works fine and I can click the button behind the list in the test project, however, when I did the same thing in the original project it doesn't work.

Anyone can point me to why this is happening???

Thank you

Comment: i think you probably have to remove on itemclicked listener for listview and set listener for individual views.

Comment: why would i need a listener for individual views in the list, I don't want them to be clickable?

Comment: Here's the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945498/how-set-listview-not-clickable

Comment: I already tried the accepted answer  and all other answers from that post.
I tried each solution by itself and in combination with other solutions and nothing seems to work for me. 
when I tried to setOnClickListener(null) for the list I got an exception saying i probably want  setOnItemClickListener(null) so I tried that and it didn't help either.

Comment: Isnt it as easy as overwriting onTouch to pass the call to the same method in the parent view?

Comment: @Nanoc, Apparently it is as simple as that, Thank you so much, I've wasted hours on this.
If you want to answer the question I'll mark it as the correct answer.
Thanks again