# Set color item listview xml

Tags: java, android, xml

i've a Navigation Drawer and i would like that when i click on an item of the listview this change color. So i've this xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:textColor="@drawable/test"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#2F2F2F"/> 

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Test code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black"/>

</selector>
```

But when i click remain the default color and not change in black. Why? Where is the problem and how can i fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is everything `black`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are changing the textColor of a textView not the view inside the ListView. It's not like css.

You must put android:textColor="@drawable/test" inside the TextView (or whatever view it is)

Comment: Yes, this works but the color do not remain after the click. Why? How can i solve?

Comment: Because you may need some state like state_active or state_activated, but I think that this only work with ToggleButton (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html)

If this doesn't work, you may add a state of your view, and when is clicked you will have to change the color manually

Answer (score 0):

use `android:listSelector="color/black"` in your listview. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908499/1008278)