# Removing the onClick highlight on all items in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm sure this is just a matter of changing some xml layout attribute(s) but I couldn't figure out which one(s).
I have a listView containing some items.
I'm looking for a way to remove the blue highlighting background that appears on an item when it is clicked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: disabling highlight on listView click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/android-disabling-highlight-on-listview-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : add this line in your listview xml code `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`

or if you want only change the selected item's backgroung color will change and rest will remain unchanged then add some additional code in your adapter `getView` method

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) convertView.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.your_list_item, null);

    }
if(postion!=SelectedPosition)
  {
   convertView.setBackgroundColor(default Color); // change color as your wish or set transparent
    }
  else
   {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125,75,236,90));// change color as your wish or set transparent
   }



    return convertView;



}
```

you can add your own logic for changing color . hope it works