# can't remove the focus of pull to refresh list view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, accessibility

I have a *pull to refresh* listView and a button. When I click the button, I want the focus for listView to be gone, I am working with talk back settings is on.

I used
`setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO_HIDE_DESCENDANTS)`.

It is not working in 4.3 devices. What should I do to fix it? It is perfectly working in 4.4 and above devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing ,

Override isEnabled(int position) method in your Adapter and return false.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
}
```

Check [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907335/android-disabling-highlight-on-listview-click/12242564#12242564).

Comment: Inform me if you facing any problem @AnanduKrishnan P.S.

Comment: have you tried
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"  OR
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" in listview