# ListView multi select - transparent color by default does not work correctly?

Tags: android, android-selector

I have multi select on my list view. Selector looks like.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/wt_list_click" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/wt_list_click" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/wt_list_click" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

But it does not work correctly.
Some strange behavior. At the end of the selection is always one cell.
If I change color from transparent to any other, everything works correctly.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/wt_list_click" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/wt_list_click" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/wt_list_click" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

What is the problem, why it is so. Can someone explain to me.

In the picture, I was initially selected 5 cells, then unselected one cell. But 5 cells remained selected.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you replace `<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />` with `<item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />`, having defined `color/transparent` as `#0000`?

Comment: @Rotwang - the same effect

Comment: And what if you "deviate" a bit from full transparency, i.e.: by defining `color/transparent` as `#01010101`?

Comment: Have you tried it on few devices???

Comment: @Rotwang This option(#01010101) also does not work too. The same effect.

Comment: @VVB Yes, as in the emulator and the different devices.

Comment: @ShaishavJogani - posted screenshot

Comment: Try different color variations. i.e.: `#0fff`

Comment: I solved!!!
I founded on stackowerflow.
<ListView 
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
/>
and my selector on root layout from list_item
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_click_selector"

Comment: Nice! Then answer yourself and accept your answer. Don't forget to cite the SO link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved!!! I founded on stackowerflow.

```
<ListView android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />
```

and my selector on root layout from list_item

```
android:background="@drawable/list_item_click_selector"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242564/1590594

Comment: OK. Now you need to accept your answer, in order to remove this post from the Unanswered Question Queue.